# ¿Como se puede ordenar un txt de mayor a menor?

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un proyecto de vuelo y me piden que muestre los vuelos del precio mas barato al mas caro...,trate con el método `sort()` pero no funcionó.

Éste es mi código:

```java
public void tablaPasajero(JTable tb, File archivo,String aerosalida,String aerollegada){
        boolean existe = false;
        String []titulos = {"ID  Aerolinea",
            "Precio vuelo", "Fecha y hora salida",
            "Aeropuerto salida", "Fecha y hora llegada", "Aeropuerto llegada"};
         DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
        String datos= "";

        try {
            BufferedReader archi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            
            
            while ((datos = archi.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] palabra = datos.split(",");
                
                
                if (palabra[5].equals(aerosalida) && palabra[8].equals(aerollegada)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay un vuelo directo para su viaje");
                        String fila[] = {palabra[1], "$" + palabra[2],
                            palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                             palabra[8]};
                        Arrays.sort(palabra);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Arrays.toString(palabra));
                        existe = true;
                        modelo.addRow(fila);

                }
                
                
            }
            if (!existe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No HAY NINGUN VUELO EN ESAS FECHAS");
                }
            
            
           tb.setModel(modelo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR " + e);
        }
                
        
    }
```

Comment: Imagino que los datos vendrán de una Base de datos, que te los de ordenados la consulta y simplemente muestralos.

Comment: No los archivo vienen de un base de datos de txt, vu1,QA,2000,01/07/2020,11:11,Internacional de Galeão,02/07/2020,20:00,Internacional de El Salvador,455,208130717,208920345,408910651,208930445,109820345 asi esta compuesto mi base de datos, lo que pido de ayuda es a la hora que yo busco un vuelo que me muestre del precio mas barato al mas caro

Comment: Ese código nunca funcionará porque estás ordenando un registro (los datos que se alojen en el array *palabra*) y no todos los registros del archivo. Lo que debes hacer es crear una clase llamada `Aerolinea`, donde sus atributos serán id, precio vuelo, fecha y hora de salida, etc. Teniendo esta clase, la puedes instanciar y crear objetos de tipo `Aerolinea` y agregar esos *objetos* en un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: De este modo podrás ordenar los objetos con el método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) (de la clase Collections). Ahí debes definir tu criterio de ordenación con la interfaz Comparator, que en este caso, sería ordenar los objetos según su precio de vuelo de mayor a menor. Aprovecha el POO de Java. Con respecto a la pregunta, el enfoque no está en ordenar los datos interno del archivo, sino, en cargar esos datos en un objeto y luego almacenarlo en una lista, así lo podrás ordenar con sort.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me puedes explicar como instanciar eso en el array